How to solve this rust "cannot borrow as mutable more than once at a time" error for the sequential method calls?
Below is my code including unit test:
use std::{env,process};
use sysinfo::{System, Process, Pid};

pub struct SystemInfo<'a> {
    sys: System,
    process: Option<&'a Process>,
    //might add some resource statistics fields
}

impl<'a> Default for SystemInfo<'a> {
    fn default() -> Self{
        SystemInfo::new()
    } 
}

impl<'a> SystemInfo<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        SystemInfo {
            sys: System::new_all(),
            process: None,
        }
    }

    pub fn initialize_system_info(&'a mut self) {
    
        println!("System name: {:?}", System::name());
        println!("System kernel version: {:?}", System::kernel_version());
        println!("System OS version: {:?}", System::os_version());
        println!("System host name: {:?}", System::host_name());
    
        self.sys.refresh_all();
    
        println!("Number of CPU: {}", self.sys.cpus().len());
        println!("Total memory: {} bytes", self.sys.total_memory());
        println!("Used memory: {} bytes", self.sys.used_memory());
        
        println!("Current directory: {}", env::current_dir().unwrap().display());

        if self.process.is_none() {
            self.process = self.sys.process(Pid::from(process::id() as usize));
        }
    }

    pub fn get_current_state(&'a mut self){
        self.sys.refresh_all();
        println!("Process CPU usage: {}", self.process.unwrap().cpu_usage());
        println!("Process MEM usage: {}M bytes", self.process.unwrap().memory()/(1024*1024));     
        //might do some resource statistics computation and update the fields   
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use rand::Rng;
    use std::time::Duration;
    use std::thread;

    #[test]
    fn test_systeminfo() {
        let mut sys_info = SystemInfo::default();
        sys_info.initialize_system_info();

        let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
        let numbers: Vec<i32> = (0..10).map(|_|rng.gen_range(90..=110)).collect();
        for num in numbers {
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(num as u64));
            sys_info.get_current_state();
        }
    }
}

The cargo build error is:
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `sys_info` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/lib.rs:66:13
   |
60 |         sys_info.initialize_system_info();
   |         -------- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
66 |             sys_info.get_current_state();
   |             ^^^^^^^^
   |             |
   |             second mutable borrow occurs here
   |             first borrow later used here

My purpose is as follow:

When the application starts, initialize_system_info() will be called to initialize the SystemInfo instance and print some basic information;
During the application running time, get_current_state is called by some specific intervals and print the resource cost of the process.

There are similar questions for this error. But I can't find a good solution. How to solve it?

The structure you're attempting to create is self-referential. See e.g. https://morestina.net/blog/1868/self-referential-types-for-fun-and-profit

@user4815162342 So, if the "process" member has no relation with "sys" member, will this error be solved?

First step is to remove the 'a lifetime from the method prototypes: pub fn initialize_system_info (&mut self) and pub fn get_current_state (&mut self). This will solve the error you've shown. But then you will hit issues with the self reference.

@passinger The way lifetimes work, a lifetime 'a means that there is a variable somewhere up the stack that owns the data. SystemInfo<'a> basically requires that someone outside SystemInfo holds the System, and SystemInfo refers to it. In safe Rust you cannot have System and Option<&Process> in the same struct.

Here is an example of how you can make it work using the self_cell crate: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c881caafd5963aa3f8d393a07fbdef20 - but please do keep in mind that this is not beginner-level Rust.
